# Unable to file_get_contents on form action in php

Tags: php

My form action is set to a php file like this:

```
<form name="addstudent" action="includes/data.php?act=enquiry" >
    <input type="text" name="studentname" class="univtext default" value="Name" />
    <input type="text" name="studentemail" class="univtext default" value="Email" />
    <input type="text" name="studentno" class="univtext default" value="Contact No." />
    <input type="hidden" name="active" value="enquiry" />
    <input type="submit" value="Apply" class="univbut" >
</form>
```

and my php file data.php is:

```
<?php
    switch($_GET['act'])
    {
        case "enquiry":
        include_once('globalvariables.php');
    $dataUrl='http://localhost:8080/databasee/track?country='.SITE_ACCESS_COUNTRY.'&region=delhi';
    $json=file_get_contents($dataUrl);
    echo $dataUrl;
    echo($json);
    }
?>
```

My dataurl is formed correctly but `file_get_contents()` function is not getting the value from the url (this url returns json true or false) in other cases it working fine, it's  just here I am not able to get it working.

I found that &region parameter in my url converts to ®ion.

Comment: what is SITE_ACCESS_COUNTRY... is it some kind of Constant...?

Comment: are you sure it doesn't enter the section with case "enquiry"

Comment: If you dont specify the method, the browser returns nothing. Only IE adds a default get method if nothing is specified.
Use: `<form action="" method="get/post">`

Comment: yes its a constant in golabl file which i included

Comment: @dkulkarni still not working i have added method="get" in form action

Comment: echo dataurl show me the correct url formed but    file_get_contents not getting that url

Comment: sorry but my issue is with file_get_contents

Comment: @Sudhir  yes its a constant in golabl file which i included and my issue is with file_get_contents

Comment: i found that &region parameter in my url converts to ®ion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$url = "http://localhost:8080/databasee/track?country=";
$param = rawurlencode(SITE_ACCESS_COUNTRY);
$contents = file_get_contents($url.$param);
echo $contents;
```

See: If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). 
Hope it helps

Comment: i found that &region in my url converts to ®ion

Comment: try using rawurlencode instead of urlencode and check, see edited code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `method="get"` in your form tag in order to use `$_GET` in the PHP code on your action page. If you want to use `$_POST`, the steps would be identical: `method="post"`. [More info here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

If that doesn't resolve your problem, you might want to verify that you can use PHP pages with parameters in their URL in a form:

`includes/data.php?act=enquiry`

vs.

`includes/data.php`

Comment: I think default form method is get.

Comment: echo dataurl show me the correct url formed but    file_get_contents not getting that url

Comment: You might try removing your hardcoded PHP parameters: `act=enquiry`. Web browsers strip off certain parts of URL headers, which might strip off your params.

Comment: @dkulkarni: no, works in FF, Chrome, Opera too., read here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3 (default is GET)

Comment: sorry for my issue is with file_get_contents not with get